matrix initialisation using pointers
int (*mat)[3]={{1,7,8},{1,2,3},{334,43,8}};

Gives errors like:
warning: braces around scalar initializer
warning: initialization of 'int *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer

But we can initialize arrays as int (*mat)[3], so why is that allocation a problem?
I tried to create a 2d array and give elements to it

You can't initialize a pointer like that, you must have something real that it can point to. What is the reason you want mat to be a pointer? Why not simply int mat[3][3]?

It won't work for the same reason as int* ptr = {1,2,3}; won't work. Pointers are not arrays.

btw, there's cglm library with a lot of ready-to-use types (arrays and structures) like [i]vec[234][s] mat[234][s] for vectors and matrixes, plus all possible maths to deal with them

you can do this:
char row1[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
char row2[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
char row3[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

char (mat*)[3] = { row1, row2, row3 };

or
char mat[3][3] = {{'a', 'b', 'c'},
                  {'d', 'e', 'f'},
                  {'g', 'h', 'i'}};

but not what you where trying because the type of the variable you have defined is a pointer to arrays of three chars... (a pointer, not an array, and the notation you use in the initializer is to initialize arrays, not pointers.

The simplest solution would be to simply use a two-dimensional array:
    int m[][3] = {{1,7,8}, {1,2,3}, {334,43,8}};

However, pursuing the idea of having an array of pointers, the problem in the OP is that e.g. {1,7,8} is not a valid initializer for an int *. To initialize a pointer to an array directly, a compound literal can be used:
    int *m[] = {(int []){1,7,8}, (int []){1,2,3}, (int []){334,43,8}};

This will create an array of pointers to the temporary objects specified by the compound literals. The lifetime of these temporary objects is the block of code where they are defined, i.e. the same as m.
While this is unusual, it offers the flexibility over the 2-dimensional array that not all rows need to have the same size. This comes at the cost of increased storage size (since row pointers are stored explicitly) and increased access time, so it cannot be recommended to use this approach for a common matrix.

The problem is not a storage size only number of indirections which will slow down access and also are not cache friendly.


But we can initialize arrays as int (*mat)[3], so why is that
allocation a problem?


int (*mat)[3] is a pointer to array, not an array!! You need to assign an array to it. You can use compound literals

int (*mat)[3]=(int[][3]){{1,7,8},{1,2,3},{334,43,8}};

int (*foo(void))[3]
{
    int (*mat)[3]=(int[][3]){{1,7,8},{1,2,3},{334,43,8}};
    return mat;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/GEs91ecEn
